# How to leave the unnecessary quotation marks when i convert a csv into a mysqldb with python?

Tags: python, mysql-python

I've got a CSV excel file, which one I want to convert into mysqldb.
It is working very fine, but in every cell in the MYSQLdb there are unnecessary quotation marks, like this: `""`.

When the cell is empty I see this: `""`

When the cell is not empty is see this: `"somethingdata"`

I can't understand, why put these quotation marks when in the csv file there are none.

Here my code, I think it is correct too.

```js
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='1234',
    db='database')
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """ 
   CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `Megnevezes` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `2015` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `2014` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `2013` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `2012` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `2011` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8"""
cursor.execute(query)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()

connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='1234',
    db='database')
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """ load data local infile 'C:/Python27/output.csv' 
into table test
character set latin1
fields terminated by ';'
lines terminated by '\n'
ignore 1 lines;
"""
cursor.execute(query)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Any ideas how can I fix this issue?

Comment: You created the file from Excel. I believe Excel makes CSV files with "" around each cell. Did you open your CSV in notepad to verify it really isn't there?

Comment: Oh. I opened it now with a notepad, and you are absolutly right.. All dataes is between "data" .. how can i leave them? How can i get a result like in excel without these signs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Use the: `ENCLOSED BY 'char'` where char will be `"`

Comment: Yeah, you are right, i have to use ENCLOSED BY, but how?
If i use ENCLOSED BY '"' this is not good, because this sign "" are around each cell, if the cell is empty too, if the cell is with data too.

Comment: @tardos93 Did you try to use it? Empty fields are changed to NULL values according to the documentation.

Comment: I found the answer!

I have to change the lines terminated too, so i have to write this : 
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\r\n'